# How to add a CSS style sheet reference to all Web forms in a Visual C# .NET Web project

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

i tried to link a css style sheet but it didnt worked.

I tried

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="~/Content/event.css" />
```

I have a folder content , in which i added the css files.

what it is wrong ?

Comment: Can you show some code in the css file that is used in the web form?

Comment: If you have place it inside `head` it will work  - but if not the symbol `~` is not translated

Comment: maybe the question is not clear - do you have a master page ?

Comment: It was missing runat="server" in the head balise .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was missing runat="server" in the head balise .

Answer (score 0):

You can have a layout page and define any public file that you need in all parts of your project as .js or .css file. Then you can use this layout in your pages. as below:

```
@{Layout="Layout.cshtml";}
```

Your question is not clear. Maybe [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_layout.asp) can help you in using layout pages. (Also pay attention to sidebar of the page, too)